# Highcharts date misunderstood

Tags: highcharts

I use highcharts from a long time until this January, that date is misunderstood with September.
I read a CSV file like this:

```
09.01.21 00:40:01;331.000;100.000
09.01.21 00:45:01;331.000;100.000
09.01.21 00:50:01;331.000;100.000
09.01.21 00:55:01;331.000;100.000
```

That is dd.mm.YY HH:MM:SS, 9 of January 2021, But on Highcharts I see 1 of Setember.

I tried to format date with dateFormat: 'dd/mm/YY' but don't work https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.dateFormat

Here the code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        title: { text: 'Log' },
        data: { csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML, itemDelimiter: ';', 
        lineDelimiter: '\n', decimalPoint: '.' ,dateFormat: 'dd/mm/YY'},
        plotOptions: {   series:  {     visible: false,    marker: {    enabled: false  }    }  },
        series: [{},{visible: true}] });
```

How I can solve?

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are not valid with the 'dd/mm/YY' format, please check this example with valid dates: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jgyu6q9h/

You can use the `parseDate` function to convert your dates to timestamps:

```
    data: {
        ...,
        parseDate: function(date) {
            var parts = date.split(' '),
                dateParts = parts[0].split('.'),
                convertedDate = '20' + dateParts[2] + '-' + dateParts[1] + '-' + dateParts[0] + 'T' + parts[1];

            return new Date(convertedDate).getTime();
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/edx3cvno/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parseDate

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date